# Exception / Policy based chrome plugin to disallow traffic to certain domainds/subdomains

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser-addons, plugins, blocking

I just installed Windows 8.1 and I forgot to note how my great plugin was called. As soon as you entered a site on Chrome it would show you (if you clicked the icon) which sites where accessed for content. Then you could tick the site, edit it (e.g. place an * instead of the specific subdomain), and at it to a defined policy group.

Next time you visit the site (or any site, if you configured that) it would block the content. If you clicked the icon, you could see which content was blocked.

Any idea how that thing was called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the plugin: KISS Privacy